On $\Re\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \geq -A \log(|t|+4)$ for some $A>0$
On page 438 of "Multiplicative Number Theory I" by Montgomery-Vaughan one finds the following statement and its verification :
Assuming RH, there exists an absolute constant $A>0$ such that
$\Re\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \geq -A \log(|t|+4)$, uniformly for $\frac{1}{2}\leq \sigma \leq 2, |t|\geq 1 $.
(where $s=\sigma+it)$
My question : Not assuming RH are there some lower bounds on $\Re\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s)$, uniformly for $\frac{1}{2}\leq \sigma \leq 1, |t|\geq C$, where C is some positive constant, reminiscent of the one above?

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

If the Riemann Hypothesis fails, then there is no such lower bound. Indeed, if $\zeta(s_0)=0$ and $\Re(s_0)>1/2$, then
$$\lim_{\delta\to 0+}\Re\frac{\zeta'(s_0-\delta)}{\zeta(s_0-\delta)}=-\infty.$$
Note that here $\Re(s_0-\delta)>1/2$ for $0<\delta<\Re(s_0)-1/2$.
For the proof, simply observe that there is a positive integer $n$ (the multiplicity of the zero $s_0$) and a positive real number $r$ such that
$$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{n}{s-s_0}+O(1),\qquad 0<|s-s_0|<r.$$
Now plug in $s=s_0-\delta$, take the real part of both sides, and then take the limit under $\delta\to 0+$.
